# Saving multiple table rows at once (Laravel 4)

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I have a table where I get the data from database than i need to update all rows at once. Inside each cell I have added input fields. Now i want to be able to update all users at once when I enter the data but I dont know how.

Below is a picture of my view:

[image: View]

```
@extends('admin/master')
@section('content')

<section class="content">
    {{Form::open()}}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-header">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <h3 class="box-title">INPUT EXAM RESULTS FOR EACH STUDENT: </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pull-right col-lg-8">
                        <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5 pull-left">
                            <select class="btn bg-navy" name="city" >
                                <option>Select City</option>
                                <option>Prishtin</option>
                                <option>Prizren</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-5 pull-right">
                             <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" name="search_input" class="form-control" placeholder="Search here...">
                                <div class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                    <?php if (isset($data)) { ?>
                    <table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>{{Lang::get('messages.stid')}} </th>
                                    <th>{{Lang::get('messages.name')}}</th>
                                    <th>Subject 1</th>
                                    <th>Subject 2</th>
                                    <th>Subject 3</th>
                                    <th>Subject 4</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>@foreach ($data as $row)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{$row->id}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$row->fname}} {{$row->lname}}</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="sub1" class="form-control" placeholder="Add marks here..."></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="sub2" class="form-control" placeholder="Add marks here..."></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="sub3" class="form-control" placeholder="Add marks here..."></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="sub4" class="form-control" placeholder="Add marks here..."></td>
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    <button type="submit" class="col-lg-2 pull-right btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</button>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{Form::close()}}
</section>

{{ HTML::script('/admin/assets/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('/admin/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('/admin/assets/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('/admin/assets/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js') }}

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#example1").DataTable();
        $('#example2').DataTable({
            "paging": true,
            "lengthChange": false,
            "searching": false,
            "ordering": true,
            "info": true,
            "autoWidth": false
        });
    });
</script>

@stop
```

//Controller

```
public function search_input(){
        $input = Input::get('search_input');
        $city = Input::get('city');
        $data = Apply::where('exam_venue', '=', "$input")
                ->where('city_applied', '=', "$city")->get();
        if (isset($_POST['save'])) {

        }
        return View::make('admin/exam/edit',compact('data'));
    }
```

Comment: By update all rows at once, I assume you mean the when search input is used? If that is the case, you need to set up server side processing and request the datatables data via ajax. Or are you submitting the form each time and reloading the entire page?

Comment: Yes. But i don't know how to do it with ajax cuz i think is better

Comment: Just so you're aware, this package does an excellent job of handling server side processing. I use it in many projects: https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables

Answer (score 0):

Your input elements need to be arrays, keyed by `$row->id` (I assume this is the primary key of your students table) to identify which student that row represents. For example:

```
<td><input type="text" name="sub1[{{ $row->id}}]" class="form-control" placeholder="Add marks here..."></td>
```

Then when you submit the data, look up the student by the array key and update their information accordingly. Something to the effect of:

```
$key = // extract id from sub1 array
Student::find($request->input($key));
// do updates here
// repeat for each sub input...
```

Comment: dont know how to continue :  $id = Input::get('id_record');
            $sub1 = Input::get('sub1');
            $sub2 = Input::get('sub2'); 
            $sub3 = Input::get('sub3');
            $sub4 = Input::get('sub4');
            Student::find($request->input($key));
            $rezult = new Exam_result();
             for ($i = 0; $i <= count($id) - 1; $i++) {
                $rezult->subject1 = $sub1;
                $rezult->subject2 = $sub2;
                $rezult->subject3 = $sub3;
                $rezult->subject4 = $sub4;
                $result->save();}

Comment: i added that in view also

Comment: how to get this id name="sub1[{{ $row->id}}]"  from the view

Comment: `$request->input('sub1')` will be an array. Then you can loop `foreach ($request->input('sub1') as $id)...`